# Row level transactions + locks and RDBMS scalability

Tags: sql, transactions, locking, scalability, atomic

I use transactions to lock on rows in my database. Generally, the number of 'things' accessing the same rows at a single time is small, however, for correctness I would still like to use transactions to have 'all or nothing' changes across multiple tables to ensure correctness.

I am wondering, if I don't ever expect the number of 'things' accessing a row to be more than a single digit, and these operations are quite small, then does locking, in this case, really affect my ability to scale the database. My understanding is that RDBMS don't scale as well as, say, NoSQL technologies because of the ACID properties. While ACID properties still apply (e.g. updating data may still require an index change, which I'm guessing is synchronous in RDBMS world?... maybe that is configurable?), given I am not having a lot of contention on a single record

While I may not have a lot of contention on a single record, I will have many many locks on records throughout the database at the same time. If these locks are isolated, am I limited in anyway by the overhead/number of simultaneous locks? Is my database scalability good?

EDIT: More context:

I use postgres and part of our product includes a large inventory stock system which maintains quantities of various inventory. There are many scenarios that can modify inventory quantity from many different ways (e.g. users can manually adjust quantity using UI or automatically when a stock request or refill event comes into our system through our exposed APIs). Between reading the stock quantity and adjusting it (assuming I am not using increment/decrement in this scenario) I hold a row level lock as part of the transaction.

Interested to hear people's thoughts
Thanks

Comment: I don't think there's a general answer to your question. Each relational database engine is quite different. For example, Oracle tends to be very smart to handle concurrent changes, as well as DB2. PostgreSQL is good but there's room for improvement. SQL Server and MySQL are not that great in this regard. I would recommend you specify exactly which engine and which version are you considering, which changes do you want to scale, and which strategy are you considering (e.g. sharding).

Comment: edited answer for more context

Comment: Just circling back on this question. I think you can get better answers at dba.stackexchange.com. This question has a lot to do with db admin and resource management.